# PHP - get values from array by specific key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How to get all values by specific key from this array?

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => Key1 [1] => Value1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => Key1 [1] => Value2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => Key2 [1] => Value12 ) 
)
```

exp.: With Key1 get these values: Value1, Value2

already tried:

```
$values = array_column($param, 'Key1');
print_r($values);
//empty array
```

Comment: This reads like homework. Key1 isn't even a key, it's a value. `0` is a key

Comment: use `array_column` [function](http://php.net/array_column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce`

```
$arr = array ( 
    array ( 'Key1', 'Value1' ), 
    array ( 'Key1', 'Value2' ), 
    array ( 'Key2', 'Value12' ),
);

$search = "Key1"; /* Update this to use */

$result = array_reduce($arr, function( $c, $v ) use ( $search ) {
    if ( $v[0] == $search ) $c[] = $v[1];
    return $c;
}, array());
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Value1
    [1] => Value2
)
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php
    $yourArray = Array( 
        0 => Array ( 0 => 'Key1', 1 => 'Value1' ), 
        1 => Array ( 0 => 'Key1', 1 => 'Value2' ), 
        2 => Array ( 0 => 'Key2', 1 => 'Value12' ) 
    );
    $desired_text = 'key1'; //your desired matching key
    $values = array();  //variable to store captured data
    foreach($yourArray as $innerarray)
    {
        //check if the first index has your desired text
        if(strtolower($innerarray[0]) == $desired_text ) //converting to lower case and matching
        {
            $values[] = "{$innerarray[1]}"; //then grab the value
        }
    }
    if(isset($values))
        print_r($values);   //show the values you've grabbed
?>
```

The output will be: `Array ( [0] => Value1 [1] => Value2 )`